# Laravel - how to do cleanup for a service before shutting down?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a service for my application. This is a deferred service and when it is used it creates a connection. Before shutting down I would like to have the opportunity to properly close the connection to the server. How do I do this using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at implementing some Terminable middleware. This executes at the shutdown stage of the framework and would be a good place to free up any resources.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: Ok. I am doing the middleware. From the middleware's terminate method I am firing a Shutdown Event. How can the instance created by the ServiceProvider listen for this event and do the cleanup?

Comment: @Liviu you can use the [terminating](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1046) method. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57096102/9618184)